# EMR jupyter notebook tab completion / autocomplete?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, amazon-emr, jupyter-lab

Is there a way to enable tab completion on Jupyter notebooks or Jupyterlabs attached to an EMR cluster?

Currently, when i start a notebook, there is no autocomplete or tab completion. Even doc strings are not shown.

I use:
emr-5.29.0
Spark 2.4.4
Hive 2.3.6
Hadoop 2.8.5
Hue 4.4.0

Comment: Could you try to use JupyterLab and then launch terminal. Run command 'ipython'. Then import pand then press 'tab' and what is the result

Comment: Also, try to download the notebook and run it from you machine running Jupyter. which kernel you are using for this notebook

Comment: Hi, did you ever solve it? I am having the same issue. It's weird that it only happens in the pyspark kernel but not in the python kernel. I tried one config setting but it didn't help me. %config IPCompleter.greedy=True

Comment: nope. I just installed my own conda through the bootstrap script and run it from there.